# Disable Tomcat JAAS?

Tags: java, tomcat

I have an active/passive nodes with Tomcat using heartbeat. When I shutdown the active node, Tomcat on passive node starts. This is a piece of the starting trace:

> INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
>  May 22, 2014
>   7:37:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
>  INFO:
>   Initialization processed in 366 ms
>  May 22, 2014 **7:37:43** PM
>   org.apache.catalina.realm.JAASRealm setContainer
>  INFO: Set JAAS
>   app name VentusProxy
>  May 22, 2014 **7:37:59** PM
>   org.apache.catalina.mbeans.JmxRemoteLifecycleListener createServer

It takes 15 seconds to initialize JAAS, that means 15 seconds more without service.

I don't use JAAS at all in my application, so I'd like to disable it or, at least, try to reduce this 15 seconds.

Can anybody tell me if this is possible and how?

Comment: Have you read the Tomcat documentation? You're not even telling the version, so it's harder for us to answer, than for you to read the friendly manual.

Comment: Sorry, it's Tomcat 6.0.39 with jdk 6u45 on Linux centos 6.5. An dyes, I read the tomcat doc about JAAS, but nothing useful found.

Comment: If the manual has nothing useful, it's not very likely that anyone else would know better. Have you tried taking out everything JAAS related from the config files?

Comment: I've removed any realms from server.xml and commented out all users/roles in tomcat-users.xml. Is there something else I should do in any config file?